# Image distorts when scailing

Tags: html, css

http://megatravel.co.nf/

This is the website I am working on. When you scale it down the responsive works fine but the slideshow images on the front get squished instead of scaling down both height and width only the width changes and the height stays the same causing the images to distort.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: Using a `height: auto` will scale the images proportionately. Also, use `max-width: 100%`. But I am not sure if the effect is what you desire as the images will not occupy the full height of the container.

Comment: Well your settings are right, but the resolution of photo the wasn't. The photo is too wide. If you need to fit the height to 100%, and you have to waste the size of width (You will see narrow image). That means you have to crop it by using background-position: center center and background-repeat: no-repeat